# Sculpt Alpha brush/texture add and substract simultanously

Tags: transparency, sculpt

Is there a way to use an alpha brush/texture where the dark carves into the mesh while the white extrudes at the same time. I could only figure out that you can set a brush to add or sub but in that way either the wihte pops out but the dark does not effect the base geo or vice versa.
Thanks!